# Common C++ framework

Tags: c++, frameworks

Has anyone experienced with [Common C++ Framework](http://www.gnu.org/software/commoncpp/)? Can it be used as a framework for a Telecom networking application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why use that? Why use an obscure framework, when a well established, well documented, peer reviewed, high quality framework like [Boost](http://www.boost.org) exists. It has good networking libraries among a million others.